# I can't seem to get anything to import a csv at all

Tags: csv, csvsimple

I have a rather large `.csv` that I would rather not type by hand into LaTeX, and am trying to use the `csvsimple` package to import it. The csv is 51 rows long, with the first few looking like the following:

```
State,Number of Dams,Land Area (km\textsuperscript{2}),Density of Dams (dams / km\textsuperscript{2}),Number of Dam Removals,Percent of Dams Removed,Number of Dam Removals with \ge 1 Publication,Percent of Dam Removals with \ge 1 Publication
Alabama,2267,"131,171",0.0173,8,0.35,0,0
Alaska,110,"1,477,953",0.0001,10,9.09,NA,NA
Arizona,372,"294,207",0.0013,3,0.81,1,33.33
Arkansas,1267,"134,771",0.0094,4,0.32,0,0
California,1529,"403,466",0.0038,173,11.31,4,2.31
```

No matter what I try, I always get:

> Incomplete \iffalse, all text was ignored after line <>

What might be wrong with my file that it will not read?

*Edit

I got it to work by removing all of the formatting from the column headers and calling `\csvautotabulate{Dam_info_breakdown.csv}.` Now I am running into a problem where I cannot seem to get it to fit on the page.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}   

\csvreader[
      longtable=lrrrr,
      table head=\toprule State & Number of Dams & Land Area & Density of Dams & Number of Dam Removals & Percent of Dams Removed & Number of Dam Removals with at Least One Publication & Percent of Dam Removals with at Least One Publication \\\midrule,
      late after line=\\,
      late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
    ]{Dam_info_breakdown.csv}{1=\State,2=\NumDam,3=\Area,4=\DensDams,5=\NumRems,6=\PercentRems,7=\NumPubs,8=\PercentPubs}{\State & \NumDam & \Area & \DensDams & \NumRems & \PercentRems & \NumPubs & \PercentPubs}

\end{document}
```

does not work and it does not provide me with a useful error code either, it just dies.

*Edit 2: this made it work

```
\csvreader[
  longtable=|r|*{7}{p{1.5cm}}|,
  table head=\toprule State & Number of Dams & Land Area (km\textsuperscript{2}) & Density of Dams (dams / km\textsuperscript{2}) & Number of Dam Removals & Percent of Dams Removed & Number of Dam Removals with at Least One Publication & Percent of Dam Removals with at Least One Publication \\\midrule,
  late after line=\\,
  late after last line=\\\bottomrule,
]{Dam_info_breakdown.csv}{1=\State,2=\NumDam,3=\Area,4=\DensDams,5=\NumRems,6=\PercentRems,7=\NumPubs,8=\PercentPubs}{\State & \NumDam & \Area & \DensDams & \NumRems & \PercentRems & \NumPubs & \PercentPubs}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  It might have been helpful if you'd shown a minimal example of how you were trying to import the csv.  But I wouldn't have expected a bare `\ge` to work without being in `$`.  (And I wouldn't call a 51x8 csv "rather large".)

Comment: I apologize for knowing absolutely nothing about how any of this works, I am brand new to LaTeX.

Comment: Please add everything needed between `documentclass{` and `\end{document}` to copy and run your code. We can't know, what you do or miss to do, else. Thanks.

Comment: More information added, I think it is everything that will be needed.

Comment: Get similar trouble. I suggest you reduce the whole thing to 1 column both  in Latex and csv, make it run and work from there. Idea is to fail early AND to localize trouble. // You may also want to scan these entries: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/csvsimple

Comment: I got it working, see above edit.

Comment: Great. However, adding a trail of varying problems will sooner or later lead to comments like “question is unclear”. It may be better to post the next question, giving all we need to know about your current problem.

Comment: But if you've gotten it working after all, you can post that as an answer.